# are ownProps passed to component by default?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

i have below snippet.

```
AnotherFile.js

import MyAccount from './MyAccount';

<MyAccount name='peace and love' />



MyAccount.js

const MyAccount = (props) => {
  // I can access props.isLoggedIn and props.setLogout, 
  // and I can access props.name too, wow
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  setLogout: () => dispatch(setLogout())
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyAccount)
```

So I pass some props to the **connected components**, and the presentational component **MyAccount** can access these props too.

Previously, if I intend to achieve that, I would add a second argument in `mapStateToProps`, like below. But now it seems it is unnecessary to pass `ownProps`? Can someone confirm please?

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  isLoggedIn: state.isLoggedIn,
  ...ownProps
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [react-redux docs](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate#ownprops-optional):

> **ownProps (optional)**
>
> [...]
>
> You do not need to include values from `ownProps` in the object returned from `mapStateToProps`. `connect` will automatically merge those different prop sources into a final set of props.

So yes, it is unnecessary to explicitly spread `ownProps` into the props returned by `mapStateToProps`.

You usually only need `ownProps` if your component needs the data from its own props to retrieve data from the store, e.g. using an `id` prop to select a certain item from a list of items.